# How to retrieve more than 3000 user details from an Active Directory group using C#?

Tags: c#, ldap

I have an Active Directory group with more than 3000 members in it. I want to retrieve all those members from that group using the LDAP connection. I tried using the below snippet but it is providing one 1-1499 members from the group. Is there is any other way to achieve the same

```
LdapConnection connection = new LdapConnection(********);
NetworkCredential cred = new NetworkCredential(********, ********, ********);
connection.Credential = cred;

List<SearchResponse> results = new List<SearchResponse>();
SearchRequest request = new SearchRequest("***********", "(objectClass=group)", System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchScope.Subtree, new string[] {"member" });

PageResultRequestControl prc = new PageResultRequestControl(1000);
SearchOptionsControl soc = new SearchOptionsControl(System.DirectoryServices.Protocols.SearchOption.DomainScope);
request.Controls.Add(prc);
request.Controls.Add(soc);

while (true)
{
       SearchResponse response = connection.SendRequest(request) as SearchResponse;

       foreach (DirectoryControl control in response.Controls)
       {
           if (control is PageResultResponseControl)
           {
                prc.Cookie = ((PageResultResponseControl)control).Cookie;
                break;
           }
       }

       foreach (var item in response.Entries[0].Attributes["member"].GetValues(typeof(String)))
       {
            var t = item;
       }

       results.Add(response);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Appears that you are hitting the MaxValRange limits.
MaxValRange value controls the number of values that are returned for an attribute of an object, independent of how many attributes that object has, or of how many objects were in the search result.

I do not do C# but We have a sample in [Java code](https://ldapwiki.com/wiki/LDAP_SERVER_RANGE_OPTION_OID_CODE_SAMPLE) that may be helpful.